# Node + Express: How to retrieve data from MongoDB via Azure

Tags: node.js, mongodb, azure, express

I am a frontend developer. A colleague has kindly built me a MongoDB/Cosmos database in Azure and allowed me to retrieve a single record into my frontend. He has since gone on holiday with no cover.

(I am confused what type of database it is, since it says Azure Cosmos DB in Azure portal, but all the code in my server.js file refers to a MongoDB.) Server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const url = 'mongodb://blah.azure.com';
app.use(express.static('static'));
const mongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient

let db;
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, async () => {
  console.log('App listening on port 3000!')
  const connect = await mongoClient.connect(url)
  db = connect.db('ideas');
});

app.get('/api/ideas/:name', async (req, res) => {
  return res.json(await db.collection('container1').findOne({key: req.params.name}));
 });
```

I want to retrieve all documents in this database. They each have an ID. But my colleague seems to have defined an API by name. From the MongoDB [docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html) I can use the command `find({})` instead of `findOne({key: req.params.name})` to return all records, but this does not work (i.e. I get no output to the console). I presume this is because of the `'/api/ideas/:name'`.

I have also tried:

```
db.open(function(err, db){ 

  var collection = db.collection("container1");
  collection.find().toArray(function(err2, docs){
    console.log('retrieved:');
    console.log(docs);
  })

 })
```

but i get an error that tells me I can't retrieve the property "open" of undefined.

Can anyone help me either: (1) work out how to change the API in Azure, or (2) rewrite this code to retrieve all records? I will also need to edit and insert records. Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to `MS Azure` account of your friend? It looks like this article might help you https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/create-mongodb-nodejs, but the point is, that your friend should been properly installed it first. So if he don't do everything like in this guide and API isn't working, then your `MongoConnectionString` won't have any sense.

Comment: @AlexZeDim Thanks for your reply. The API does work. The problem is that it isn't structured the way I want it. He left it to prove to me I could fetch records. But he has organised this by name. I want to get all records, regardless of name. Do you know how I do this?

Comment: As long as we don't see the DB it would be a problem, but first-things-first, does you connection with DB opened successfully? According to your code, does `db.open(function(err,db) { console.log(db) }` returns the connection itself. I guess that thought connection doesn't even open.

Comment: @AlexZeDim I can't even start the server if I have db.open in server.js. Where should db.open code be? If it is within app.listen after connect.db('ideas') I get an unhandledpromiserejectionwarning. If it is by itself after app.listen function has ended, the server won't even start.

Comment: To be honest, I am not so good with default MongoDB driver, cause I am using `mongoose` driver. I could provide a snippet from one my projects with the example of the connection string build with `Express.js` (https://gist.github.com/AlexZeDim/1d38d596f9eeb8bf2e2fe62c9c963976)

If the following code snippet with your own credentials give you an error (on connection), then something wrong with deployment of your database.

Comment: Also, if the CosmosDB deployed fine, and you have opened connection with your database successfully, but you do not know the exact endpoint for receiving data, then, if you don't have access to Azure account itself, you could do nothing about it. Cause you could guess it for all eternity. (It will be much easier to re-deploy the database once again)

Comment: @emma Do you have any update?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrive data from Mongo DB in nodejs espresso application, I suggest you use the package `mongoose`.

For example

1. Create `mongo.js` file to add connection details

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const  accountName= 'testmongo05',
const  databaseName= 'test',
const  key= encodeURIComponent(''),
const port: 10255
const mongoUri = `mongodb://${env.accountName}:${key}@${accountName}.documents.azure.com:${port}/${databaseName}?ssl=true`;
function   connect() {
mongoose.set('debug', true);

return  mongoose.connect(mongoUri, { 
    useFindAndModify : false,
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true

});
}

module.exports = {
connect,
mongoose
};
```

2. Define models

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = new Schema(
  {
    userId: { 
        type: String, 
        required: true, 
        unique: true
    },
    name: String,
    saying: String
  },
  {
    collection: 'Users'
  }
);

const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

module.exports = User;
```

3. CURD operations

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const User = require('./module/user');
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

require('./mongo').connect().catch(error => console.log(error));
//list users
app.get('api/users', async (req, res) => {
    const docquery = User.find({});
     await docquery
      .exec()
      .then(users => {
        res.status(200).json(users);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error);
        
      });
});
// get user by userId
app.get('/api/user/:uid', async (req, res) => {
   
    const docquery =User.findOne({userId:req.params.uid })
    await docquery
      .exec()
      .then(user => {
        if (!checkFound(res, user)) return;
        res.status(200).json(user);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(500).send(error);
        
      });
            
  });

// create
app.post('/api/user', async (req, res) => {
    const originalUser= { userId: req.body.userId, name: req.body.name, saying: req.body.saying };
    const user = new User(originalUser);
    
    await user.save(error => {
        if (checkServerError(res, error)) return;
        res.status(201).json('User created successfully!');
        console.log('User created successfully!');
    });
  });
  
  //update user by userId
  app.put('/api/user/:uid', async (req, res) => {
    
    const docquery =User.findOneAndUpdate({userId: req.params.uid}, req.body)
     await docquery.exec()
                    .then((user) =>{
                        if (!checkFound(res, user)) return;
                        res.status(200).json("User update successfully");
                        console.log('User update successfully!');
                     })
                    .catch(error =>{
                        res.status(500).send(error);

                    })
            
  
  });
  
  //delete user by userId
  app.delete('/api/user/:uid', async (req, res) => {
    const docquery = User.findOneAndRemove({userId: req.params.uid })
    await docquery.exec()
                  .then(user =>{
                        if (!checkFound(res, user)) return;
                        res.status(200).json("user deleted successfully!");
                        console.log('user deleted successfully!');
                  })
                  .catch(error =>{
                    res.status(500).send(error);

                  })

  });



function checkServerError(res, error) {
    if (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
      return error;
    }
  }
  function checkFound(res, user) {
    if (!user) {
      res.status(404).send('user not found.');
      return;
    }
    return user;
  }
```

4. Test

a. Create user
[image]

b. get user
[image]

c. List Users
[image]

d. Update User
[image]
[image]

e delete user
[image]
[image]